# Floating elements: two ways of doing it, what is more correct?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm just trying to put a div next to the other. I've found 2 different ways. You have them here below. But I don't know what of them is more correct..

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.jander1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="jander1">jander1</div>
  <div class="jander1">jander1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.jander1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid;
}

.jander2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:100px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="jander1">jander1</div>
  <div class="jander2">jander2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javi

Answer (score 1):

Floating both is simpler, and means that you don't have to be careful if you add more elements next to the first two. Floating just one is more unusual, more often used when you want actual float effects (like text wrapping around the floated element).

As krs1 said, you'll probably want to use some method to clear your floats. The easiest way is to have a containing element (as in your second example), and to apply either `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to it. This can have side effects (if content from the boxes overflows), but does not complicate your markup.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think about your content. The markup of your content should reflect your content; don't let CSS determine the class attributes you use. The nature of that content also affects what CSS you should be using.

## Case 1: Different content in the 2 `<div>` elements

If we're talking about different content between the two `<div>` elements, such as an image and some text...

```
<div class="profile-picture"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0be84773790974af8d6a1d5d55801736?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Profile picture for Richard" class="" /></div>
<div class="about-me">My name is Richard and I work as a software developer!</div>
```

... use different classes. The neither is a `jander` so don't include jargon class attributes to accomodate your CSS. Class attributes are [element identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) and should make semantic sense.

### Case 1.1: The Left `<div>` has a fixed width

Once you get to your CSS, in a case like this one, the image has a fixed width which probably isn't subject to a lot of change; as such you can use technique #2 from your question to give the second `<div>` a `margin-left`:

```
.profile-picture {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
}
.about-me {
    margin-left:81px;
}
```

[Here is a JsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/rqXQt/)

### Case 1.2: The Left `<div>` has a variable width

But what if we need that image to some times be bigger, sometimes be small? What if we don't have knowledge of the image's size when we're writing our CSS?

```
<div class="profile-picture"><img src="http://media03.linkedin.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/1/000/09a/108/11e3bdd.jpg" alt="Profile picture for Richard" class="" /></div>
<div class="about-me">My name is Richard and I work as a software developer!<br />blah<br />blah<br />blah<br />blah<br />blah</div>
<div class="profile-picture"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0be84773790974af8d6a1d5d55801736?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Profile picture for Richard" class="" /></div>
<div class="about-me">My name is Richard and I work as a software developer!<br />blah<br />blah<br />blah<br />blah<br />blah</div>
```

... one of those images is `128px` tall and the other is `80px` tall.

We can then `float` the first `<div> while simply targeting the other with an`overflow-x:hidden;`:

```
.profile-picture {
    float:left;
}
.about-me {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

[Here is another JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FJPLd/).

## Case 2: Similar content in the 2 `<div>` elements

Then by all means give them the same `class` attributes!

```
<div>
    <div class="column">Here is content for column 1!</div>
    <div class="column">Here is content for column 2!</div>
</div>
```

If they are supposed to behave identically, target them with the same rules and `float` them both to the left. If they don't behave identically, you can generalize the considerations above; do you know how wide that first `<div>` should be? If so, go ahead and use the `margin-left`. Otherwise use `overflow-x`.

Answer (score 0):

If they work, they work.  Option 1 looks good, I've run similar patterns before.

However you're going to run into issues if you attempt to put a block element beneath floating elements.  After the second 'jander' class element add this:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Just add `overflow: hidden` to the css for both.

Comment: @theazureshadow bump for answer and mysterious name.

Answer (score 0):

Since both div share styling, I would go with the first example. I would also add a clear:both to your #container since it is wrapping the two divs which are floating left.

Since you have a margin-left in your 2nd div only, I would either use a pseudo-class like #container div:first-child or an id/class to add the margin.